# Trying to save list outut to file

Tags: python-3.x, list, save

I am attempting to generate a roughly 2 million number sequence password list for use in an `aircrack-ng` penetration test.

```
list(range(2163000000, 2164999999))
```

This is the one line of code that produces the correct list of numbers.  However everything I have tried does not save the output to a file. I am using the Windows version of Python 3 if that is of any help.

Comment: What have did you try? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Tested on Windows Python 3.73

```
f= open("results.txt","w+")
results = list(range(2163000000, 2164999999))

for i in results:
    f.write(str(i) + "\n")
f.close()
```

Just be aware that the output file is rather large at 24 mb.